# export mysql query to csv on button click

Tags: php, mysql, csv

so i have a php code that shows a table from the mysql database
there is also a filter field which filters the table.

i need help exporting the results of the table to a csv file when the button "export data" is clicked.

how do i do that?

below is the code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
include("config.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TAD Customer Search</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<style>
BODY, TD {
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
}
</style>
</head>


<body>

<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
<label>Search: </label>
<input type="text" name="string" id="string" size="20" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST["string"]; ?>" />
<label>Country: </label>
<select name="country">
<option value="">--</option>
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." GROUP BY country ORDER BY country";
    $sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
        echo "<option value='".$row["country"]."'".($row["country"]==$_REQUEST["country"] ? " selected" : "").">".$row["country"]."</option>";
    }
?>
</select>
<input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Filter" />
  </label>
  <a href="index.php">Reset</a>
</form>
<br />
<table style="text-align: left; width: 100%;" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: left;"><input type="submit" name="btnexportdata" value="Export Data" /></td>
      <td style="text-align: right;">
      <form method="post" action="input.php">
      <input type="submit" value="Add" />
      </form></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4">
  <tr>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Account Number</strong></td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Company Name</strong></td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Country</strong></td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Email</strong></td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Phone Number</strong></td>
    <td width="150" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><strong>Brands</strong></td>
  </tr>
<?php

if ($_REQUEST["string"]<>'') {
    $search_string = " AND (cname LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR email LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR accnumber LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR pnumber LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%' OR brands LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["string"])."%')";  
}
if ($_REQUEST["country"]<>'') {
    $search_country = " AND country='".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["country"])."'";  
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." WHERE id>0".$search_string.$search_country;
$sql_result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection ) or die ('request "Could not execute SQL query" '.$sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($sql_result)>0) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql_result)) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row["accnumber"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["cname"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["country"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["email"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["pnumber"]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row["brands"]; ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
} else {
?>
<tr><td colspan="6">No results found.</td>
<?php   
}
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the code you can try

```
 // Define  database connection variable dynamically
    $DB_Server = "localhost";           //MySQL Server    
    $DB_Username = "root";              //MySQL Username  



    $DB_Password = "";                  //MySQL Password     
    $DB_DBName = "test1";    //MySQL Database Name  
    $DB_TBLName = "tabletest";          //MySQL Table Name   
    $filename = "excelfilename";        //File Name
    //create MySQL connection   
    $sql = "Select * from csvtable";
    $Connect = @mysqli_connect($DB_Server, $DB_Username, $DB_Password) or die("Couldn't connect to MySQL:<br>" . mysqli_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
    //select database   
    $Db = @mysqli_select_db( $Connect,$DB_DBName) or die("Couldn't select database:<br>" . mysqli_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());
    //execute query 
    $result = @mysqli_query( $Connect,$sql) or die("Couldn't execute query:<br>" . mysqli_error() . "<br>" . mysql_errno());

    function cleanData(&$str) 
    {
        if ($str == 't')
            $str = 'TRUE';
        if ($str == 'f')
            $str = 'FALSE';
        if (preg_match("/^0/", $str) || preg_match("/^\+?\d{8,}$/", $str) || preg_match("/^\d{4}.\d{1,2}.\d{1,2}/", $str)) {
            $str = "'$str";
        }
        if (strstr($str, '"'))
        $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

// filename for download
$filename = "file_" . date('Ymd') . ".csv";
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
header("Content-Type: text/csv;");
$out = fopen("php://output", 'w');
$flag = false;

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if (!$flag) 
        {
        // display field/column names as first row 
        fputcsv($out, array_keys($row), ',', '"'); $flag = true; 
        }
    array_walk($row, 'cleanData');
    // insert data into database from here
    fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
}
fclose($out);
exit;
//end
```

Comment: im a total beginner so where do i add this in my code and how do i connect it to the button to extract only the filtered results?

Comment: place this code in  the separate file name it something. then make a button and in action attribute of that button write link to that file

Comment: im guessing that the below
 $sql = "Select * from csvtable";
should be changed to my query... but since its on a different page how to i put the query here?